# Backup MySQL database some tables structure only

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL DB with a bunch of tables that we are migrating.

Some of the tables have quite a lot of historical data that isn't useful for us and to cut down on the time it will take to dump the data and restore it we would like to specify that some tables dumped structure/schema only while making sure the other tables include the data.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this with mysqldump or xtrabackup.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--ignore-table` to exclude specific tables.
In this case it makes sense to create two dumps: one for the database structure and one for the data itself and append the latter to the first dump.

```
# dump db structure
mysqldump -h host -u user -p --no-data db_test > db_test.sql

# append db data (without `CREATE TABLE` statements)
mysqldump -h host -u user -p --no-create-info \
  --ignore-table=db_test.table1 \
  --ignore-table=db_test.table2 db_test >> db_test.sql
```